# How to automatically pop-up keyboard?

Tags: android, xml, keyboard

I have Edit Text field where I have to input a password, but I have to push this field. How to automatically pop-up keyboard without touching the Edit Text?

There is an Edit text xml field:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editPasswd"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="phone"
android:password="true"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this code in the point where you want to display the keyboard (may be in oCreate?)

```
    EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPasswd);

    ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
        .showSoftInput(myEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Comment: this worked for my:        <activity android:name=".first"
                           
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you mean to automatically pop it up when the activity starts. If so, adding this to the `activity`-tag in the manifest solved it for me (unlike Erfan's answer):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
```

Answer (score 1):

One line in the Java class:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```