# Trying to get Android keyboard to popup on activity startup

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-keypad

I want the Android Keyboard to pop-up on the startup of my activity. A simple google search shows that you just have to `requestFocus` which I do in my `.xml`, but it still doesn't pop up. Am I making any minor mistake that is causing this not to work?

**Testing on:**

Physical 4.1
Emulator 2.2

**layout.xml:**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="To:"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804493/how-to-automatically-pop-up-keyboard

Comment: I tried all of the answers, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```java
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener( new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```java
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);         
inputManager.showSoftInput(input, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: I get an error on `getActivity()` so I replaced it with `this.getSystemService...` but it does not work.